# How to drag PanResponder with the same easing like dragging a ScrollView?

Tags: react-native

I have a draggable horizontal view (a scale). To make it horizontally draggable, in `componentDidMount`, I added:

```
this.currentPanValue = 0;
this.panListener = this.state.pan.addListener((value) => this.currentPanValue = value);
```

On the component state, I have a `dragX: new Animated.Value(0)`. To the to the PanResponder, I set:

```
onPanResponderRelease: (e, gestureState) => {
  this.state.dragX.setOffset(this.currentPanValue);
  this.state.dragX.setValue(0);
},
```

... which makes it horizontally draggable, all set!

However, the "dragging" experience is not like having a `<ScrollView horizontal={true} />`.

I wonder is there any way I can make the dragging experience with the PanResponder the same like dragging a ScrollView - with same "easing", "bouncing", "velocity" and etc?